# Material UI Card with Select in it resizes itself on change selection

Tags: css, reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui, grid

I have a Card component with a Grid component inside it and two Grid items: one is a simple TextField and the other is a Select component (a drop down menu). Whenever I change the Selection, the Card resizes it self. How can I make it stay the same size?

Also, is it possible to make the Card bigger and make it shrink a little bit every time I resize the window? At the moment it just shrinks when the windows is "phone-size" but it happens all at once and I want it to shrink step by step a little bit.

This is the code I used:

```
<Card>
     <CardContent>
          <Grid
            container
              direction="row"
              justify="center"
              alignItems="center"
              spacing={2}
           >
                <Grid
                  item
                  xs={12}
                  sm={6}
                  lg={8}
                >
                  <TextField
                    id="standard-basic"
                    label="Title"
                    fullWidth
                  />
                </Grid>
                <Grid
                  item
                  xs={12}
                  sm={6}
                  lg={4}
                  alignItems="center"
                  justify="center"
                >
                  <FormControl>
                    <InputLabel fullWidth id="ageSelectLabel">
                      Age
                    </InputLabel>
                    <Select
                      labelId="ageSelectLabel"
                      id="ageselect"
                      fullWidth
                      align
                    >
                      <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
                      <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
                      <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
                    </Select>
                  </FormControl>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
```

Comment: Does it resize due to different content sizes from dropdown options ? If that's the case you should consider adding a minWidth property which would be the width of the maximum element in the dropdown selection

Comment: I added the minWidth and also the maxWidth property and I managed to make it not resize, thank you for the advice! Do you happen to know the answer to the other question?

Comment: @Sonsos I don't know the answer directly, but usually, gradual resizing has to do with css media breaking points, look for xs, s, m, xl, and media screen. That maybe will help you figure it out. Edit. As I see from your code, you have already applied these values to Grid component, so look if there is something similar for the component you want. Also, try to follow the guidelines of material-ui, as these people always follow the trend in design patterns, so before trying something different, at least be sure it follows some good practices.